# unable to detect "unexpected identifier" in parseJSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to get data from data from database and doing json_encode

```
    $data = json_encode($results);
```

When I have put echo($data); die(); I have got the below result

```
    [{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"Wa","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"187002.04","RANK":"1"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"CVS","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"127948.68","RANK":"2"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"McK","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"81079.29","RANK":"3"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"Car","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"65320.42","RANK":"4"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"Krog.","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"31977.95","RANK":"5"}]
```

And in jquery code I am trying to parseJSON $data as below

```
    $(function () {
     var data = new Array();
     data = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $data; ?>'); //error occuring here
    //other code goes here
    });
```

I am getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` near `data = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $data; ?>');`

I am getting the below output in

```
  [{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"Wa","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"187002.04","RANK":"1"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"CVS,Inc.","PRODUCT_GROUP'S":"ACP","NET_SALES":"127948.68","RANK":"2"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"McK","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"81079.29","RANK":"3"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"Car","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"65320.42","RANK":"4"},{"CAL_DATE":"01-JUN-13","CUSTOMER_TEXT":"Krog.","PRODUCT_GROUP":"ACP'S","NET_SALES":"31977.95","RANK":"5"}]
```

Can any one please tell me why I am getting error in that line? Thanks in advance

Comment: No error for me : http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/ogQEZw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a valid json so you don't need to parse it:

```
data = <?php echo $data; ?>
```

---

I guess you want to use it like this:

```
$(function () {
 var data = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
 data = $.parseJSON(data); //error occuring here
//other code goes here
});
```

---

From the documentation:

> ***Takes a well-formed JSON string*** and *returns* the resulting ***JavaScript value***.

check this from the docs:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' ); // results in {"name" : "John"}
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

`'{ "name": "John" }'` is a string which is in json format.

Comment: Correct, you stringify a JSON, just to re-parse it afterwards.